# USB Webcam problems

Tags: usb, video, webcam, camera

I have logitech webcam, and i am having some problems to use it correctly. I am writing a program with OpenCV, and i want to control some parameters of the camera, such exposure, focus and frame size.

When i use the following code, OpenCV returns false.

```
  VideoCapture cap(0);

  bool ok = cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_SOME_PROPERTY, some_value);
```

OpenCV returns false for all property i try to use. But i still can grab images with OpenCV normally.

When i open cheese, it recognizes the camera and starts streaming the video, but when i try to change the frame size, the stream stop and an error message appears saing "There was an error playing video from the webcam".

When i open guvcview, it recognizes that the device is on /dev/video0, but dont start the streaming. The window stays dark and some error messagens appears on terminal.

```
.
.
.
.
vid:03f0
pid:9207 
driver:uvcvideo
checking format: 1196444237
Requested Format unavailable: get width 800 height 600 
VIDIOC_G_COMP:: Inappropriate ioctl for device
fps is set to 1/15
drawing controls

control id: 0x009a090a failed to get value (error -1)
Checking video mode 800x600@32bpp : OK 
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
Ignoring empty buffer ...
.
.
.
.
```

I already have tried with another webcam, a HP webcam this time, and the same happens. I already have tried to use this two webcans on another computer, and they work well.

Has been more than six months since this problem started to happen. In the past i have ignored the problem because i stoped using the cameras, but now a want to use them.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and i already try to reintall my entire system. Dont work.

Thank you everybody.